# fail php redirect when click ok sweet alert

Tags: php, redirect, sweetalert, sweetalert2

```
 <?php
       //  my button auth

         $autorizar    = "<a onclick=\"confirmar(event)\" href=\"scripts/autorizaTicket-".$resultado['id']."-".$_SESSION['ticket_id']."\"><button title=\"Autorizar\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" ><i class=\"fa fa-check\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></button></a>"; 
    ?>



    <script>
    function confirmar(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      swal({
        title: 'Espere',
        text: "¿Estás seguro?",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Sí, vamos'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          window.location.href = e.target.href;
        }
      })
    }
    </script>
```

the alert stops waiting for confirmation but when you press ok it does not redirect me to the php target that I indicated, what do I do wrong?

Comment: What version of Sweet Alert are you using? Try doing a `console.log(result);` before your `if` case to see the value.

Comment: appears "ReferenceError: result is not defined[Saber más]"

Comment: i am using sweet alert 2 @ChinLeung

Comment: Where did you put your `console.log`?

Comment: in the browser hahaha , sorry , i am noob  . i have return TRUE in green in console screen

Comment: Put the `console.log` inside your `then` callback, right before the `if (result.value) {`

Comment: i have put the console.log in code now

Comment: this return true https://snag.gy/gV6lQi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an old version of Sweet Alert where the `result` passed in the callback is a simple boolean.

Just update your condition to the following:

```
if (result) {
    window.location.href = e.currentTarget.href;
}
```

Or update to the latest version of Sweet Alert.

Comment: now after pressing ok, I'm redirected but I get "undefined" on my website

Comment: @JuanOrtiz I think the event is detecting the `button` as the `e.target`. Try using `e.currentTarget` instead.

Comment: this make a change . now appears "null"

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Can you do a `console.log(e.currentTarget);` to see what element it's returning?

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Can you show me the rendered HTML of the `a` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>  function confirmar(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      swal({
        title: 'Ir a Google',
        text: "¿Estás seguro?",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Sí, vamos'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          let linkElement = e.target
          while (!linkElement.href) {
            linkElement = linkElement.parentElement
          }     
          window.location.href = linkElement.href
        }
      })
    }</script>
```

I have solved, I've shared for who might need it